# Form validation and design on iPad

Tags: css, html, forms, validation, ipad

I know this question is not specific to a programming issue, but it is about programming and design in general.

I'm writing a web app that will be used on a single iPad device (at the moment anyway), and I'm having trouble with two things: form validation and form design.

Firstly, I can't get form validation to work at all using HTML5 on the iPad. It works fine on a pc, but does absolutely nothing on safari or chrome on the iPad. Submitting the form does not trigger a validation error, and the CSS does not recognize `:invalid` pseudo tags. How do I this working? h5Validate for jquery does not seem to work. Here's my code:

```
        <form action="/contact_submit.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required autocorrect="off" autocaptialize="words" autofocus maxlength="30" inputmode="latin-name" placeholder="Full Name">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" inputmode="email" placeholder="jon@sample.com">
            <label for="tel">Phone:</label>
            <input id="tel" name="tel" type="tel" required inputmode="tel" maxlength="11" placeholder="2285555555">
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" autocapitalize="sentences" placeholder="Any additional information you'd like us to know"></textarea>
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```

Secondly, and more of a side question, I'm  not great at the creative aspect of form design, so are there any jquery or other pre-developed solutions for form layout on a kiosk?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering that, because iPad does not use form validation properly, I had to manually add the validation classes to the h5validation script, as described in the documentation.